# Canvas sprite library or tutorial

Tags: animation, sprite, javascript, javascript-framework

I am looking for some simple library for javascript to manage animations. 
I need something realy simple, just to "parse" animation to frames. I want to handle everything by myself, i want just to know, how many frames is in animation and how to get the frame i want.

I did some digging on google, i found one which is realy nice (sprite.js) but it is too big and it will force me to rewrite my app.

Is there simple lib, or a tutorial how to work with animated images? (gif and others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight way to get single frame from gif in JavaScript.